# Sometimes HttpURLConnection.getInputStream executes too slowly

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

We have next code.
Sometimes we should wait 10-20-40 seconds on the last line.
What can be the problem?

Java 1.4

```
URL url = ...;
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.connect();
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
try
{
   outStream.writeObject(objArray);
}
finally
{
   outStream.close();
}

InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
```

**UPDATED:

Next code fixes the problem IN ECLIPSE.

But it still DOES NOT WORK via Java WebStart:(**

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
conn.setDoInput(true);  
conn.setDoOutput(true);  
conn.setUseCaches(false);  
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");  //<---------------
conn.connect();
```

But why?

**UPDATED one more time!

Bug was fixed! :)**
We worked with connections not in one class but in two.
And there is following line in the second class:

```
URL url = ...  
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "1000");  //<------------
conn.connect();
```

Note:
`setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "1000")` is root cause of the problem.

Comment: Why is openConnection called twice?

Comment: It is just misprint.
Corrected.

Comment: Why is *Content-Length* the issue, anyway?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'We had a similar issue which is caused by buggy keep-alive in old Java. Add this before connect to see if it helps,

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

or

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```

Comment: How about the 2nd approach? You really need to post a TCP dump to see exactly what the issue is. I don't think it's DNS though because which occurs in connect() call.

Comment: It seems to me that keepAlive=false helps. But why?

Comment: Without a trace, I am just guessing. The HTTP request has keepalive but no content-length, the server doesn't know where is the end of the request so it keeps waiting. The default timeout on Apache is 30 seconds. When keepalive is turned off, the OutputStream will be closed, which notifies the server request is done.

Comment: wireshark/ethereal, tcpdump, snoop. It really depends on your OS.

Comment: Setting the `connection=close` header should work. Maybe you didn't set the request property correctly. It should be done prior to `connect()`. Setting the system property `http.keepalive=false` does basically the same, but then as a low-level workaround. When not specified manually, the `URLConnection` uses it to set the `connection` header. That it doesn't work in webstart is simply a security restriction. But anyway, the `setRequestProperty("Connection", "close")` must work. Try again and verify if you did anything right.

Comment: Improve the speed using https in my case, very useful

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, found out it was caused by IPv6.

You Disable it from code using:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

You can also disable it via the command line using : `g-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 2):

Try it with an IP address. To see if it's a DNS problem.

Comment: We jave this problem on different computers and in different countries :(

Comment: Did you have a look at it with Wireshark?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, so i change to HTTPClient from Apache, follow a example:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost("www.myurl-to-read");

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                              .setSocketTimeout(8000)
                              .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                              .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
                              .build();

request.setConfig(requestConfig);

request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be something from network sub layer... Should be hard to find it.

But what about the [`setReadTimeOut()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) with low value and a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would guess is that your DNS server isn't responding well.

Can you experiment with changing symbolic domain names to numeric IP addresses before you start? Or can you do each request twice (just for experimentation) and see if the first request is significantly slower than the second?

Google has put up a DNS server at (among others) 8.8.8.8 . They claim it's faster than most other DNS servers. Give that a try!

Comment: We jave this problem on different computers and in different countries :(

Comment: In the same company? May the DNS the same within your private network?

Comment: It's not so much a matter of where you do the DNS lookup as which DNS server handles the destination. If you're accessing a site in Timbuktu with a slow network and so on, the problem could be there. I wouldn't dismiss this possibility without first having looked at response times for DNS lookups.

Comment: Production and test environments are different.

Comment: I give up - I can't help you.